# Deploying Django in Local Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I've built a Django Web App which is running on my local system (127.0.0.1:8000) without any errors. I'm also able to run the same app in my system running "python manage.py runserver xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8000" where "xxx.xxx.x.xxx" is my static IP. Then I connected that IP with my domain (let say "www.some domain name.com"). But the problem is when I try to load the page "**www.some domain name.com**" I'm not getting anything but when I try to load the page "**www.some domain name.com:8000**" it's working perfectly. So my question is how to get rid of that port number (i.e., :8000) which is attached to my domain name so that whenever I load "www.some domain name.com" I get  exactly same result as "www.some domain name.com:8000".

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of port number and serve your web app on the default HTTP port (port 80) You can use a web server like Nginx or Apache to forward incoming HTTP (80) requests to your web app (8000).

For example Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.some domain name.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

which listens to port 80 and forwards it to 8000

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is the standard and default port that browsers use.

If you search for `http://your_website.com` it will "automatically" assume the desired address is `http://your_website.com:80`.

For websites that use https, the port is 443, i.e. `https://your_website.com:443`